# Parameters in anonymous function

Tags: haskell, lambda, anonymous-function

I've been practicing with anonymous functions and got the following:

```
takeWhile' :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
takeWhile' f xs = foldl (\x y z -> if (f x) && z then x : y else y) xs [] True
```

which is basically a rewrite of the takeWhile function already in Haskell.

For those who don't know, the takeWhile function takes a list and a function and returns a new list with every element in the original list that satisfies the function until one of them gives false.

From my point of view everything seems to be correct, I have 3 arguments x y and z ready to use in my anonymous function, x being the list of numbers, y the empty list where I'll be inserting every element and z is basically a debouncer so that if one of the elements doesn't meet the requirements, we don't insert any more.

And yet Haskell gives me the following error:

```
"Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ Bool -> [a]"
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Unless you plan on `xs` being a list of functions and providing a function as the initial value, the anonymous function can only take two arguments.

Comment: I think this needs to be a `foldr`, as that's the only way application of the fold can reduce to an application of the lambda, allowing for the third parameter to be provided.

Comment: `foldl` takes two parameters: the accumulator `x` and the element `y`. What is `z` doing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fold function in `fold` takes as parameters the accumulator `x`, and the element `y`. So there is no `z` that is passed.

But even if that was somehow possible, there are still other issues. `x` is the accumulator here, so a list, that means that `x : y` makes no sense, since `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` takes an element and a list, and constructs a new list.

You can however easily make use of `foldr` to implement a `takeWhile` function. Indeed:

```
takeWhile' p = foldr (\x -> if p x then (x :) else const []) []
```

We here thus check if the predicate holds, if that is the case, we preprend the accumulator with `x`. If not, we return `[]`, regardless of the value of the accumulator.

Due to the laziness of `foldr`, it will not look for elements after an element has failed the accumulator, since `const []` will *ingore* the value of the accumulator.